# Hi, I try to do a Mern Stack authentification and it's been 2 weeks since I can't solve this error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Error says:
Server running on port 5000
Error: MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.crea teConnection()` is a string.
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

This is my server.js:

```
require ("dotenv").config({path: '../config.env' });
const express = require('express');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');

//Connect DB
connectDB();

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/auth'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;


const server = app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));

process.on("unhandledRejection", (err, promise) => {
    console.log(`Logged Error: ${err}`);
    server.close(() => process.exit(1));
})
```

This is my db.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const connectDB = async() => {
      await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useCreateIndex: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useFindAndModify: true
        });

        console.log("MongoDB connected");
    };

module.exports = connectDB;
```

And this is my config.env file:

```
PORT=5000;

MONGO_URI=mongodb://localhost:27017/mernauth
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not able to read the env file properly.

1. It looks like your dotenv is not imported correctly.
2. First try to console log process.env.

Try to import dotenv as:

```
require('dotenv').config()
```